# HttpClient and WebClient give 401 error yet direct link in browser works

Tags: c#, wordpress, woocommerce, httpclient, webclient

I'm the middleman on an integration project between a Woocommerce site and a retail POS system. The POS is trying to synchronize products with the Woocommerce store. The site has an SLL certificate so all communication is over SSL. The POS vendor tells me they are using TLS1.2. We have a URL that contains a customer key and secret so I can't paste the full URL here, but the problem is as follows...

The same URL pasted directly into the browser works perfectly well, returning the expected JSON payload. The same URL used with a .NET WebClient or HttpClient returns a 401 Not Authorized error. Here is an example of an integration test using WebClient;

```
[Test]
public void DownloadString_UsingWebClient_ReturnsNonEmptyResponse()
{
    using (var client = new WebClient())
    {
        var response = client.DownloadString("https://demostore.mycompany.com.au/wp-json/wc/v2/settings/tax/woocommerce_prices_include_tax?consumer_key=ck_xxxskeyxxx&consumer_secret=cs_xxxsecretxxx");

        Assert.IsNotEmpty(response);
    }

}
```

And here is a similar test using HttpClient;

```
[Test]
public async Task DownloadString_UsingHttpClient_ReturnsNonEmptyResponse()
{
    using (var client = new HttpClient())
    {
        ServicePointManager.SecurityProtocol = SecurityProtocolType.Tls12;
        var response = await client.GetStringAsync("https://demostore.mycompany.com.au/wp-json/wc/v2/settings/tax/woocommerce_prices_include_tax?consumer_key=ck_xxxskeyxxx&consumer_secret=cs_xxxsecretxxx"");

        Assert.IsNotEmpty(response);
    }

}
```

Both tests never make it to the Assert. Just to reiterate, if I take the same URL and paste it into my browser, everything works as expected. I've tried a couple of different things, including enforcing the security protocol type (as in the latter example), but it is all just a poke in the dark, really.

The website is using the latest version of Wordpress, and it is in a shared linux hosting environment.

Is there something I'm missing with WebClient and HttpClient? Do I go back to the web hosting company and find out if there is something in the configuration that would prevent a .NET client from performing the same as a browser (I have logged a support ticket to this effect, but I'm not getting any headway)?

Comment: 401 means u need authorization, i.e. you might need to add auth cookies to your request

Comment: Try adding `User-Agent` header.

Comment: Wow - I had to google what you both meant, but adding the user-agent header did the trick! Now how do I mark an answer if it is in the comments @zaitsman?

Comment: @Damo let me add it as an answer

Comment: Just to clarify, I added this line to the WebClient example, and it worked immediately; client.Headers.Add("user-agent", "Mozilla/4.0 (compatible; MSIE 6.0; Windows NT 5.2; .NET CLR 1.0.3705;)");

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found that usually when something works in the browser, but not outside of it, that suggests that the API relies on `User-Agent` header being present in the request.

One of the reasons for this may be a reverse-proxy/firewall in front of that API.

Answer (score 1):

If you're in a corporate network and the browser works and your code doesn't, it's likely you're missing the Proxy settings for the `WebClient` or `HttpClient` instance.

I typically pass a `HttpClientHandler` instance with `Preauthenticate = true` and `UseDefaultCredentials = true` to the `HttpClient`.

Comment: Not in a corporate network, but I will certainly put this one away for future use, thanks.