# Yahoo Finance API file_get_contents 429 Too Many Requests

Tags: php, nginx, curl

I am using Yahoo Finance's API at https://query1.finance.yahoo.com/v8/finance/chart/Ticker with php's file_get_contents and getting "failed to open stream: HTTP request failed! HTTP/1.0 429 Too Many Requests" but when I use curl to the same URL from the command line of the server I get an actual response! I verified that both of the requests are coming from the same IP.

I am not sending many requests - I sent maybe 40 get requests last night and then my first request today failed. My question is - has anyone seen the same type of problem? I read that the limit was 100 requests per hour - which I was well under!

Any advice would be appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since you noticed that curl works, try adding a user agent to your request to mimic curl.

```php
<?php

$url = "https://query1.finance.yahoo.com/v8/finance/chart/nvda"; 

$options = [
    'http' => [
        'method' => "GET",
        'header' => "User-Agent: curl/7.68.0\r\n"
    ]
];
$context = stream_context_create($options);
$response = file_get_contents($url, false, $context);

if ($response !== false) {
    echo "Response: " . $response;
} else {
    echo "Request failed";
}

?>
```

I was running into the same issue in Rust and adding a similar user-agent to the request fixed it. You can also try a browser user agent such as `Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/122.0.0.0 Safari/537.36`.

Comment: This worked! I had tried some options like this, but the curl user-agent is brilliant.

Answer (score 0):

Just to clarify, I added this line to the WebClient example, and it worked immediately; client.Headers.Add("user-agent", "Mozilla/4.0 (compatible; MSIE 6.0; Windows NT 5.2; .NET CLR 1.0.3705;)");

This article fixed it for me:

[HttpClient and WebClient give 401 error yet direct link in browser works](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47410910/httpclient-and-webclient-give-401-error-yet-direct-link-in-browser-works)